# VBA .range.find error "With block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba

I just cant seem to see what the problem is here.

I tried:

```
Dim findRow As Integer
Dim findRow As Range
Dim findRow As Excel.Range
```

they all give the same error. 
I tried .with and without .width

Here is my code:

```
Dim findRow As Excel.Range

findRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AllAgents").Range("F:F").Find(What:=strEmail(1), LookIn:=xlValues)

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AllAgents")
    MsgBox (.Cells(2, 6))
    findRow = .Range("F:F").Find(What:=strEmail(1), LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
```

The MsgBox shows the correct value, so it is there.

This is the error I get:[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Set findRow = ...`  - you are assigning an object variable, so `Set` is required.

Comment: Argh!!! Didnt see that one coming :-D  Thanks Tim.  One more thing - now the findRow contains the value of the cell, but I need the number of the row, not the value of the cell.  Do I need to change xlValues to something else or how can I get the row containing the value?

Comment: Ahh got it - findRow is now a real object variable, so I have to treat it as such and do a MsgBox (findRow.Row()) if I want the row :-)

Comment: Yes but typically `findRow.Row` (no parentheses)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard - And it is a bad habit to put brackets around parameters when calling something that is not returning a value - so use `MsgBox findRow.Row` rather than `MsgBox (findRow.Row)`.  In this case it won't matter, but in many cases it can lead to errors, i.e. if the code you are calling is expecting something to be passed by reference - the brackets are forcing it to be passed by value instead.

Comment: Specifically adding parentheses around an expression will cause it to be *evaluated* - for example passing `findRow` to `TypeName()` will give you "Range", whereas passing `(findRow)` will give "String": evaluating a single-cell Range will call its default property (Value) and the result of that call is passed to `TypeName()`

Comment: @YowE3K and TimWilliams - thank you both for teaching me something new.